# Custom options on CiviEvent registration forms to handle breakout session choices

Tags: civievent

A common need in event registration systems is the ability to allow participants to select from a list of concurrent "breakout" sessions that will occur in various time slots during the course of the event.

I know this *could* be achieved using custom fields in a profile inserted into the event Online Registration form. I don't like this because (1) it's "[clumsy](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=10082.0)" as Dave Greenberg admits (and the average user will not enjoy the process of creating a custom field group, custom fields/options, and including them in a profile—no way!), and (2) Some of the fields/options will only be used one time and would clutter up the permanent list of custom fields in the system.

Ideas on alternatives are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried a bunch of approaches, and price sets are definitely the best approach here.

- Create a "Select" price set for each group of concurrent sessions (e.g. "Workshop Session 1", "Workshop Session 2", etc.).
- This also allows you to charge different amounts for different sessions, if some incur an additional cost.
- The price set options selected will be stored on the participant record as "Fee Level", and can be easily searched/displayed.

Comment: Perfect, that does exactly what I need. I was not aware of how to fully utilize Price set fields. Light bulbs turned on when I realized that you can set `Amount` to "0" and then choose to hide the amount from display.